# Which function do i have use date/Time picker using Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to make date time picker like this format.

[please Click this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLlkf.png)

Also each time, if i clicked 3 times , cannot click that time anymore,

is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Please share a sample code which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'd like to make an exact replica of of the Eiffel Tower.

Answer (score 0):

[image]React UI have this components, check the third one -Date & Time pickers.

https://material-ui.com/zh/components/pickers/

Comment: I need calendar and time

Comment: Yes, it is calendar and time pickers, and see the picture of picker added for u